# How to remove current element from List in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, loops, data-structures

How do I remove current element from list while iterating using `for loop`?

I have below a list containing:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("a");
        list.add("a2");
        list.add("a3");
        list.add("a4");
        list.add("a5");
        list.add("a6");
        list.add("a7");
        list.add("a8");
        list.add("a9");
        list.add("a10");
        list.add("a11");
        list.add("a12");
        list.add("a13");
        list.add("a14");
        list.add("a15");


        List<List<String>> parts = chopped(list, 4);
        System.out.println(parts);
```

which gives me output below like this:

```
[[a, a2, a3, a4], [a5, a6, a7, a8], [a9, a10, a11, a12], [a13, a14, a15]]
```

Now I am trying to remove first list from the list in below program:

```
for(int i=0; i<parts.size(); i++){

    System.out.println("Loop number: "+i);
    System.out.println("Current list: "+parts);         

    Thread.sleep(2000);
    parts.remove(i);

    System.out.println("After removing: "+parts);
}
```

Here I am using `parts.remove(i);` to remove current element, it gives me the following output:

```
[[a, a2, a3, a4], [a5, a6, a7, a8], [a9, a10, a11, a12], [a13, a14, a15]]
Loop number: 0
Current list: [[a, a2, a3, a4], [a5, a6, a7, a8], [a9, a10, a11, a12], [a13, a14, a15]]
After removing: [[a5, a6, a7, a8], [a9, a10, a11, a12], [a13, a14, a15]]
Loop number: 1
Current list: [[a5, a6, a7, a8], [a9, a10, a11, a12], [a13, a14, a15]]
After removing: [[a5, a6, a7, a8], [a13, a14, a15]]
```

This one removes first current element `[a, a2, a3, a4]` which is correct but in running second loop it removes `[a9, a10, a11, a12]`.

I want to remove it loop wise like below:

```
[[a, a2, a3, a4], [a5, a6, a7, a8], [a9, a10, a11, a12], [a13, a14, a15]]
[[a5, a6, a7, a8], [a9, a10, a11, a12], [a13, a14, a15]]
[[a9, a10, a11, a12], [a13, a14, a15]]
[[a13, a14, a15]]
[]
```

**Edited:**

When I try to access List inside List using `parts.get(loopNumber)` or parts.get(i)` it throws an exception error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at gmailSendLaptopGUI.MyProgram.main(MyProgram.java:156)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are editing the list and at the same time reading it.

You have to decrease the counter when you remove an object from the list.

```
for(int i=0; i<parts.size(); i++){

    System.out.println("Loop number: "+i);
    System.out.println("Current list: "+parts);         

    Thread.sleep(2000);
    parts.remove(i--);

    System.out.println("After removing: "+parts);
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me with other thing? When I am trying to print by using `parts.remove(i--);`
`System.out.println("List: "+parts.get(i));` It throws an exception `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1`

Comment: @Babarencho Try moving your print statement to before `parts.remove(i--)`.  If you have the print after that line, then for the first iteration (`i=0`), `i` is decremented by 1 after that line, so `i=-1`, which is not a valid array index.

Comment: @Vikram Thanks for your comment. I am trying to access List inside List in loop I am getting the following error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 1. Can you please help me for the same?

Comment: Yes, @Vikram is right. Another approach will be: `System.out.println("List: " + parts.remove(i--);` The remove function from ArrayList will return the removed element.

Comment: @Babarencho I would recommend you step through the code yourself (either mentally or with a debugger). Your error is telling you that you are trying to access element 2 of an array that only has 1 element.

Comment: @Vikram Yes a debugging/dry run will help to solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

One more way to do is this:

```
 int loopNumber = 0;
    while (!parts.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Loop" + loopNumber);
        parts.remove(0);
        loopNumber++;
        System.out.println(parts);
    }
```

Not sure why are you putting Thread.sleep().

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying to access List inside List in loop I am getting the following error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 1`. Can you please help me for the same?

Comment: where are you calling parts.get(loopNumber)?

Comment: `loopNumber++;`
`System.out.println(parts.get(loopNumber));` After loopNumber++

Comment: @Babarencho loopNumber is just for printing the loop, you can't get 2 as you have already deleted it. This will lead to exception. Can you please tell what you want to achieve with `parts.get(loopNumber)`

Answer (score 1):

You have already fine answers but I think that if you want to keep a `for` statement, **a simple and readable way** is not specifying increment (`i++`) in the `ForUpdate` part of the `for` statement as it is not mandatory and you always want to suppress the current first element (`parts.remove(0)`).

```
for(int i=0; i<parts.size(); ){
   System.out.println("Current list: "+parts);         

   Thread.sleep(2000);
   parts.remove(0);

   System.out.println("After removing: "+parts);
}
```